# How to use lib rasa without the tensorflow pipeline

Tags: tensorflow, rasa

I am trying to use the rasa lib to create a chatbot and am getting the following error while trying to create the project:

`The TensorFlow library was compiled to use AVX instructions, but these aren't available on your machine.`

So I would like to know how I can install the rasa lib without using the tensorflow pipeline.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the [Pretrained Embeddings](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/choosing-a-pipeline/) pipeline, that is based on spaCy and sklearn. To do this, change the pipeline line in your `config.yml` file to

```
pipeline: "pretrained_embeddings_spacy"
```

Although, it's worth figuring out why Tensorflow is not working on your machine, as there are use cases for which Tensorflow supervised embeddings [make more sense](https://blog.rasa.com/rasa-nlu-in-depth-part-1-intent-classification/). People in [this thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24548) recommend installing Anaconda as a solution.